# 2px of different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, height

I have 2px difference between Chrome and Firefox in the height of input, why?
(I don't want to specify height to input element)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
p {
font-size: 11px;
font-family : Verdana;
}
input {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
font-size: 11px;
font-family : Verdana;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<p>
<label>Text</label>
<input type="text" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, If I put Arial font instead of Verdana, the sizes are correct. Why?

Thank you.

[image: Example]

Comment: Check the computed (user-agent) styles, it could be padding, line-height, etc.

Comment: If I reset all the elements with: * {margin: 0; padding: 0} the result is the same.

Comment: I wouldn't waste a moment trying to figure out a 2 pixel layout difference between browsers.

Comment: You SHOULD be using a CSS reset.

Comment: Doesn't work css reset @Diodeus.
Kevin: I need the same height, It's important for my design.

Comment: The whole point of a CSS reset is to give you a common baseline across browsers. Your styling goes on *top of that*.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue with Firefox not rendering a Search box same as Chrome. I used the following css line and it fixed it:

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }
```

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)

```
input { line-height:17px; }
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. With line-height: 17px the height of input in Firefox is 17px and Chrome 19px.

Answer (score 0):

Set [line-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) to 1em:

```
input {line-height: 1em;}
```